How does this question not relate to philosophy? How can we prevent incorrect VTCs?
This question, to anyone who has even taken a cursory look at the notion of chance/probability, seems pretty obviously about philosophy, which also explains why many posters (one of whom in her own words spent 20 years in philosophy) decided to bother answering it.
And yet, there are already 3 close votes with the following reason:

While this question may be related to philosophy or occur in a philosophical context, the question itself doesn't seem to be about philosophy, and is therefore not a good fit for our site.

There are entire articles about interpretations of probability or chance that deal with very similar questions. What probability means, what chance means, the ontological nature of chances, the ontological nature of probabilities, how subjective or objective they are, are all (ironically) objectively part of philosophy.
Is this site really such an avenue where questions can be closed purely by the opinion of randoms (who may or may not have other motives or who may or may not have read much philosophy), even when questions seem to be obviously about philosophy?
This is quite literally the fourth time this has happened to me, where for three of those times, the questions were re-opened. This has happened to other users recently as well, and also to KristianBerry, who is also a prominent user of this site and now (rightfully) wants to leave. Are we stuck with this system?
EDIT: Looks like KristianBerry has indeed left

It's very disappointing to see pressure on the scope for nuance philosophical debate being narrowed by an arbitrary capacity to close discussions with a minimal amount of community consent.  I can understand (and lament) Kristian's decision to close their account, given that this appears to be a difficult mechanism to overcome within the context of the functionality of the site.
What I do encourage some caution around is taking this out on particular users, or pitching this as a problem with difficult individuals.  You could very much create this same problem with a single difficult person with no philosophical axe to grind whatsoever - a hostile agent determined to close the site would have little difficulty procedurally creating the requisite accounts to close every question, and the moderation team would appear powerless to stop it.  The fact that this is possible makes it a functional weakness in Stack Exchange, at least as PhilSE has configured it, rather than specific users who may be exploiting that weakness for their own reasons.
Unfortunately, this is a longstanding problem that stabs at the heart of the internet simpliciter - it is easier for rogue forces to disrupt systems that presume collaborative contribution.  If we are presuming that community moderation is our mechanism for flagging questions that are inappropriate to our content, then community astroturfing will allow for the seizure of that mechanism.  No mechanism that is driven by a community approach to content identification can realistically hope to solve it.
In an ideal world, I wonder if we might address this with something like a "First Pass Algorithmic" approach, where community members are the panelists to answer questions brought to them by a combination of community flagging and content detection.  At first we don't vote to close, but simply flag.  AI might review new submissions, as well as those flagged, to see which should be brought to the close panel, and add these to the "flagged for concern" review queues, and community members could check the list of those up for consideration.  We give the algorithm the capability to reject votes to close if they confidently determine that the questions look sufficiently like real philosophy questions - there may be some false negatives, some "pseudophilosophy" questions that pass muster, but these are not terrible slips if so.
The alternative, of course, is an increase in the voluntary moderation team. But really, who wants to do that?

There is a second alternative, and that is to place terms limits to keep fresh moderators who frequently contribute; one might point out that it is quite possible for moderators to retain their status but infrequently contribute.

@JD I think moderators who infrequently contribute aren't necessarily a bad thing. Some distance from the day-to-day arguments is useful for being a good janitor.

@Kaia You keep on making good points, and I promise I will grow to dislike you.

@JD Term limits can be generalized to all users. ie someone who answered 100 questions 10 years ago be not considered as hi rep as someone who answered in the last year (assuming otherwise similar quality profile). This can be effectuated via the concept of "negative interest" Old rep "deprecates" negative-exponentially or some such non constant decreasing function. Of course it's delicate because right now we have the opposite problem as well: sudden jump in new users that are both overflowing new questions. And then other newbies overusing the VTC

The VTC war being waged on this site has driven at least one long-term productive member off the site.  And yes, this is a legitimate question in philosophy, so the VTC rationale is-- clearly invalid.
However, we are also being spammed on this probability subject, and VTC based on spamming/duplicate is often legitimate.
Relative to probability, several posters over the last several years have opened multiple threads on probability and its objectivity or interpretation over the last two years.  This was one of the obsessions of thinkingman and his ban evading avatars, as well as Syed, and user80226. Almost all of them could be answered by noting that the way to do math/probability is to treat math as an abstraction in "math space", treating knowledge or confidence/expectation as a second (or second and third) "space", and treating our physical world as yet another different "space". Most of these questions are tied to our incorrect intuition that these three spaces are necessarily linked, or to our invalid expectations that we have better understanding/confidence than we should about our views (priors tend to be drastically overstated in human psychology).
When we are dealing with vague terms, uncertain evidence, and incomplete coupling between formalisms, knowledge, belief, and our world (I.E. when doing philosophy), then trying to mathematicise/numericize these relationships just become a process of self-deception.  Philosophy evaluated the mathematization and/or formalization of all our philosophy thinking in the first half of the 20th century as part of the analytic movement and its formal language "solution", then abandoned them as self-delusional.  This is why Popper, Quine, and Wittgenstein all abandoned the rationalist project of formalizing all statements about philosophy into logic languages to avoid lack of clarity, and instead reverted to natural language, and more organic concepts of problem statement and evaluation.
This question is likewise answerable by the above paragraph and the 2nd half of the one above it.  When we have hundreds of questions over the last two years that can all have the same answer, I am sympathetic to the closure vote, to try to reduce spamming the site.
BOTH the spamming, AND the invalid VTC campaign, are problems for this site.  As Paul Ross notes, misbehaving users can break basically any community on the internet.  I urge both the askers to drastically limit their question quantities, and the VTC campaigners to self-question their VTC thinking.  Please all of you, stop breaking our site!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@causative Aren't Meta questions basically asking for opinions?  I don't think I have seen meta comments moved to chat previously, and the different purpose of Meta strikes me as calling for this to be at least rare, rather than automatic.

You may have a point there. My perception is that long conversations are easier to have in chat, since you don't have to scroll past every individual comment to get to the latest and don't have to be as worried about comments getting randomly deleted (by other users or mods), but of course they are also less visible and comment upvotes are gone. In this case though the conversation had become fairly hostile with a lot of flagged comments (mixed with some decent points) so moving it to chat was the easiest way to deal with it.

You ask:

How can we prevent incorrect VTCs?

We can't. We can only build enough esprit de corps to have a ready pool of collaborators interested in voting to reopen, which is something that I have been encouraging for 5 years. The loss of Kristian, despite his idiosyncratic style, probably is demonstrative of the same forces that keep some contributors from being more active.

You sound like the Laws of SE are etched into the fabric of the universe like gravitation.  I don't see why the categorical "We can't." Sure its harder than an intraphil-SE decision but I bet that dozens other non-STEM, non top-4 also suffer the demarcation problem. For such subjects, the problem of ppl using VTCs against questions they dislike rather than inappropriate for the site are sure to exist
